# I can't set the decimal value of SalesQty correctly on client while trying AIF Sales Order

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to create sale order on client with AIF services. I can set values of other fields correctly but when i'm trying to set SalesQty field as for example 20 it's created as 1.00. I don't understand the problem here.

```
var salesLine = new AxdEntity_SalesLine()
{
     ItemId = txtUrunId.Text,  //"1015188", 
     SalesQty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMiktar.Text),  //20, 
     SalesUnit = "ADET", 
     TaxGroup = "IHRACAT", 
     TaxItemGroup = "S%0", 
     InventDim = new AxdEntity_InventDim[] { dim }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the decimal conversion works as expected? If it does, it might be that some downstream logic changes the value.

Comment: @FH-Inway Yes, the value of the SalesQty is 20.00 on the client side but its 1.00 on the AX.

Comment: Consider posting the solution as answer. This allows it to be found easier and also be marked as accepted answer. It can also be upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also another field as SalesQtySpecified and that field is boolean. I assigned it to true and now I can assign SalesQty correctly.

```
var salesLine = new AxdEntity_SalesLine()
{
     ItemId = txtUrunId.Text, 
     SalesQty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMiktar.Text),
     SalesQtySpecified = true, // THIS IS THE SOLUTION
     SalesUnit = "ADET", 
     TaxGroup = "IHRACAT", 
     TaxItemGroup = "S%0", 
     InventDim = new AxdEntity_InventDim[] { dim }
};
```